# Use wc_enqueue_js only on specific pages - nested add_action

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

In my plugin, I'm trying to add inline script using `wc_enqueue_js` only on the cart page. The rest of the plugin is also executed only on the cart page.

The code below works fine, but I don't like the fact that I need to repeat `if (! is_cart() ) return;`. This may not look like a big issue, but my other plugin with a similar problem has several lines of conditions based on what the user selected in plugin settings, that are mixed with multiple actions:

```
// Run plugin.
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ); });
function ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ) {    
    if (! is_cart() ) return; // Only if it's a cart page.  
    // Do stuff.    
}

// Enqueue js script inline using wc_enqueue_js.
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { acau_enqueue_script ( $args ); });
function acau_enqueue_script( $args ) { 
    if (! is_cart() ) return; // Only if it's a cart page.  
    wc_enqueue_js( '    
        <<<my jquery code>>>
    ' );    
}
```

The following doesn't work - the inline script doesn't appear in the HTML:

```
// Run plugin.
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ); });
function ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ) {
    if (! is_cart() ) return; // Only if it's a cart page.
    // Enqueue js script inline using wc_enqueue_js.
    add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { acau_enqueue_script ( $args ); });
    // Do stuff.    
}

function acau_enqueue_script( $args ) { 
    wc_enqueue_js( '    
        <<<my jquery code>>>
    ' );    
}
```

The following works, but the inline script appears in the HTML twice (one script directly below the other). If I put `echo 'test';` in the first line of function `acau_enqueue_script`, it appears only one time on page:

```
// Run plugin.
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ); });
function ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ) {
    if (! is_cart() ) return; // Only if it's a cart page.
    // Enqueue js script inline using wc_enqueue_js.
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', function() use ( $args ) { acau_enqueue_script ( $args ); });
    // Do stuff.    
}

function acau_enqueue_script( $args ) { 
    wc_enqueue_js( '    
        <<<my jquery code>>>
    ' );    
}
```

Is there any smart way to make it work without repeating page conditions?

Comment: No idea why, but for the second snippet, changing the priority of the nested `add_action` from the default (10) to 20, causing the parent and child `add_action` to have a different priority solved the problem and now everything works perfectly: `add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { acau_enqueue_script ( $args ); }, 20);` I would be grateful for an answer why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No idea why, but for the second snippet, changing the priority of the
>   nested `add_action` from the default (10) to 20, causing the parent
>   and child `add_action` to have a different priority solved the problem
>   and now everything works perfectly: `add_action( 'template_redirect',
>   function() use ( $args ) { acau_enqueue_script ( $args ); }, 20);`

The reason is quite simple. Because WordPress supports nested hooks, which means you can add another callback to the same/parent hook (e.g. `template_redirect` in your case), and the additional callback would be called *if the priority is greater than the parent callback's priority*.

- Case 1: In this case, only the `some_func2()` that would be executed. Because its priority is `12`, which is *greater than* the parent callback (i.e. the closure).

  ```php
  add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
      add_action( 'template_redirect', 'some_func', 11 );  // first child hook
      add_action( 'template_redirect', 'some_func2', 12 ); // second child hook
  }, 11 ); // parent hook
  ```
- Case 2: In this case, both `some_func()` and `some_func2()` would be executed. Because their priority is, once again, *greater than* the parent callback's.

  ```php
  add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
      add_action( 'template_redirect', 'some_func', 11 );  // first child hook
      add_action( 'template_redirect', 'some_func2', 12 ); // second child hook
  } ); // parent hook with the default priority (10)
  ```

So when registering nested hooks, make sure the callback's priority is greater than the parent's.

#### Alternatives to using nested hooks

*So this is specific to the original question about `wc_enqueue_js()` only on the cart page.*

You can try one of these, which worked well for me:

- Hook to `wp`, then hook `acau_enqueue_script()` to `template_redirect`:

  ```php
  add_action( 'wp', function(){
      if ( is_cart() ) {
          add_action( 'template_redirect', 'acau_enqueue_script' );
      }
  } );
  ```
- Hook to `template_redirect`, then hook `acau_enqueue_script` to `wp_footer` (WooCommerce uses this hook to print custom JavaScript code added via `wc_enqueue_js()`):

  ```php
  add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
      if ( is_cart() ) {
          add_action( 'wp_footer', 'acau_enqueue_script' );
      }
  } );
  ```