# Nested Actions and Filters

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, actions

It is possible and a good practice to combine filters and actions, it is necessary to take into account the order in which they are executed, a graphic example https://images.app.goo.gl/zSCcfuMNTEm5wj7n8

Here I show you the example of the code I want to make:

### Action parent + Filter child

```
add_action( "init", "parent_action");
function parent_action()
{
    add_filter( "any", "child_filter");
    function child_filter() 
    {

    }
}
```

### Action parent + Action child

```
add_action( "init", "parent_action");
function parent_action()
{
    add_action( "any", "child_action");
    function child_action() 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, WordPress does support nested hooks. And my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/345071) might help you.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.